# Play Framework not picking up changes to public files

Tags: playframework, gulp

I am using scala play framework [2.4.2] to build the backend of a Single Page App with Angular. I have all my front end stuff in its own folder and am compiling and minimising the assets with gulp.js.

After every change my front end is recompiling into

```
 /ui/dist/assets
```

and I have added this to my build.sbt

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Assets += baseDirectory.value / "ui/dist/assets"
```

Then in my routes I am doing this:

```
GET         /assets/*file                        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

This works all fine except when I make a change to the files and they are rebuilt play will not find the new files. They will exist in the ui assets directory but I will get a 404 error within my browser. Restarting play will fix it and if play incrementally compiles (which is not done when gulp runs) then things work.

The documentation mentions that the assets get packaged into the application Jar file and it makes sense that it would error until this is rebuilt. However is there a way to force this? the auto incrementer isnt picking up the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, So I had a lot of trouble trying to find an solution where you can add another folder to the classpath of play. Which wasn't ideal anyway because the developers explicitly don't want assets in the classpath

Came up with this hack. Essentially just touching a file that is in the classpath forcing a reload.

In my gulpfile after building:

```
gulp.task('reload', [], function() {
  fs.closeSync(fs.openSync('../conf/test', 'w'));
});
```